How to make cropping when doing motion-tracking look super smooth? (using OpenCV and yolo v8)
I'm using yolo to track a face in a video on a frame by frame basis, and then I'm using OpenCV to crop the video (with some padding) around the speakers face so it creates a motion tracking type effect. (short example here: https://www.instagram.com/reel/DCIFkFEObkE/?hl=en)
The problem I'm running into is my final crop looks "shaky". Like it's flickering a bit. I think this is because every frame yolo is updating the coordinates, and so there's a slight change in x, y and because of that it creates this shakiness/flickering effect. Here's what mine looks like compared to the example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MKHWK-5EH5abSq6i32r71GWld76tN1GP/view?usp=sharing
You can see there's this "shakiness" type look to it. it's especially apparent when the speaker is relatively still.
I've tried doing an exponential moving average and a few other averaging techniques but none have fixed it.
Is my fundamental approach of doing a frame by frame crop wrong? or is there just some smoothing algorithm or some dumb mistake that you think I may be making? Any advice is mega appreciated!

"sensor" fusion. kalman filter or something adjacent (simpler or more complex). yolo is detection. it never drifts, but it is jerky. there are optical tracking methods that don't know what they see, they drift, but they follow very smoothly. grab one of each, fuse, done. you should also try AI models explicitly for tracking. they might contain mechanisms to enhance smoothness of tracks. your approach is sensible, but it seems to be "not enough". that minimal jerk is to be expected, if you react proportionally/linearly to every new position update. look up noise reduction in general. apply here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
